# Windows command+ Browser bookmark

Tags: windows, browser, command-line, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

Kindly help is there any command to access browser bookmark via command line and open the bookmarked URL's via command line or powershell or wmic.

Also is there any event in windows which tells when a bookmark was accessed.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: For chrome browser you can see all bookmarks under C:\Users\%Username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

Comment: @pravprab i want to know the command to open a bookmarked webpage via command prompt/CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, there is no event to let windows know that any browser executed or accessed a bookmark.
Normally the bookmarks are stored inside a file like "bookmarks.adr" or similar which contains all the information the browser has about the stored bookmarks (except thumbnail or favicon data). If you want to access the URLs and open them, you need to parse the bookmarks file and extract the URLs. Doing this on the commandline with batch only is tricky at least... unless you just need something simple like a `findStr` on `http` which would extract all those URLs beginning with `http` (check out `findStr /?` and `type /?` and try something like `type bookmarks.adr | findStr http > urls.txt` which needs to be processed further with a for loop maybe (check out `for /?` on the commandline).

PowerShell might get the job done more easily but I don't know about the specific format of the bookmarks file and the browser you target. The browsers have their own format and thus the parsing is different for each browser class (maybe it is more unified than I am aware of, since most browsers are based on Chromium nowadays and therefore certainly share the same bookmarks file format).

Hope this helps. Good Luck with your project :)